# Cylindrical lens aberration fixed by roll

Tags: optics, lenses

I have two cylindrical lenses essentially forming a beam expander.  The problem that I am having is that I am seeing a very strange aberration.  The image becomes "squashed".  Cylindrical lenses only focus in one direction unlike spherical lenses so with a circular input beam a crisp vertical line should form at the focal point of the converging lens (If I just use the converging lens...no beam expander).  But, at the focal point of just the converging lens instead of seeing a vertical line, the line is slanted.  Now looking at the beam expander system the image begins as a nice crisp expanded circular beam but as I continue looking at the progression of the beam the image looks as if it is folding over itself and squashing into a horizontal line.  If I add in some relative roll between the converging and diverging lenses The squashing is improved but not perfect.  I wanted to know if this kind of aberration is common or if there is a defect in the lenses I am using.  In the Zemax simulations this should not be happening.  It might be important to note that the converging lens is essentially saturated.  The input beam is collimated in such a way that the maximum sized circular beam is sent through the lens without clipping.

[image]

Comment: You say you're using the cyldrinal lens pair as a beam expander, which is not an imaging system.  So what do you mean when you say the image gets squashed?  You should have an input beam profiled and an expanded output beam profile.  Are your cylindrical lenses are aligned to be focusing on the same plane?  When you say the focal point, you mean the common focal point of the two lenses?  When you say you're looking at the progression of the beam, where exactly are you looking?  After both lenses?  Have you profiled the incoming beam to check for aberrations (especially astigmatism)?

Comment: a diagram could be helpful too

Comment: @Joe I tried clearing up your questions and I added a simple diagram.  Please let me know if I didn't hit all of your questions.

Comment: What and where is the object? Is this just a laser beam? And as Joe mentioned, where are the focal planes of both lenses ?

Comment: what are the focal lengths of your two lenses?

Comment: Please add lines illustrating the beam path as it passes through the lenses to the focus (or to the otherwise unfocused result).